How to handle google OAuth2 sign (google sheets service)
I have a problem, how do we authenticate google sheets, google apis when running an instance on the backend the code I have provided needs to be run on an cron
How Do I implement this, with a cron job, I have used repl function of auth in this to generate tokens but the browser instance doesn't work on the cli
    async getMajorAreaZoneFromAreaName( majorAreaZoneDto: MajorAreaZoneDto ) {
    const { areaName } = majorAreaZoneDto;
    const areaZones = await this.getAreaZones();
    const areaZoneMap = new Map();

    for( const row of areaZones ) {
      const [ , key, value ] = row;

      if( ! areaZoneMap.has( key ) ) {
        areaZoneMap.set( key, [] );
      }
      areaZoneMap.get( key ).push( value );

      if( value == areaName ) {
        return key;
      }
    }

    throw new ValidationError( "Area Doesn't Exist" );
    }

/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import { authenticate } from "@google-cloud/local-auth";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as fsPromises from "fs/promises";
import type { OAuth2Client } from "google-auth-library";
import { google } from "googleapis";

import { NotFoundError, ServiceUnavailableError } from "../../../shared/helpers/error";
import { CREDENTIALS_PATH, SCOPES, TOKEN_PATH } from "../constants/sheets.constant";
import type { ISheetsService } from "../interfaces/sheets.service.interface";

@Injectable()

   export class SheetsService implements ISheetsService {
  authProviderX509CertUrl: string;
  authUri: string;
  clientId: string;
  clientSecret: string;
  projectId: string;
  redirectUris: string;
  tokenUri: string;

  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService
  ) {
    this.authProviderX509CertUrl = this.configService.get<string>( "GSHEET_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL" );
    this.authUri = this.configService.get<string>( "GSHEET_AUTH_URI" );
    this.clientId = this.configService.get<string>( "GSHEET_CLIENT_ID" );
    this.clientSecret = this.configService.get<string>( "GSHEET_CLIENT_SECRET" );
    this.projectId = this.configService.get<string>( "GSHEET_PROJECT_ID" );
    this.redirectUris = this.configService.get<string>( "GSHEET_REDIRECT_URIS" );
    this.tokenUri = this.configService.get<string>( "GSHEET_TOKEN_URI" );
  }

  async authorize() {
    await this.createCredintialsFiles();
    let client: OAuth2Client = await this.loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if( client ) {
      return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate( {
      keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
      scopes: SCOPES,
    } );
    if( client.credentials ) {
      await this.saveCredentials( client );
    }
    return client;
  }

  async createCredintialsFiles(): Promise<void> {
    if( ! fs.existsSync( CREDENTIALS_PATH ) ) {
      const credentials = {
        installed: {
          auth_provider_x509_cert_url: this.authProviderX509CertUrl,
          auth_uri: this.authUri,
          client_id: this.clientId,
          client_secret: this.clientSecret,
          project_id: this.projectId,
          redirect_uris: [ this.redirectUris ],
          token_uri: this.tokenUri,
        }
      };
      await fsPromises.writeFile( CREDENTIALS_PATH, JSON.stringify( credentials, null, 2 ), "utf-8" );
    }
  }

  async listMajors( auth: OAuth2Client, spreadsheetId: string, range: string ) {
    const sheets = google.sheets( { auth, version: "v4" } );
    if( ! sheets ) {
      throw new NotFoundError( "Sheets Not Found" );
    }
    const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get( {
      range,
      spreadsheetId,
    } );
    const rows = res?.data?.values;
    if( ! rows || rows.length === 0 ) {
      return;
    }
    return rows;
  }

  async loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    const fileExists = fs.existsSync( TOKEN_PATH );

    if( ! fileExists ) {
      return null;
    }
    const content = await fsPromises.readFile( TOKEN_PATH, "utf-8" );
    const credentials = JSON.parse( content );
    return google.auth.fromJSON( credentials ) as unknown as Promise<OAuth2Client>;
  }

  async readData( spreadsheetId: string, range: string ) {
    const auth = await this.authorize();
    return this.listMajors( auth, spreadsheetId, range );
  }

  async saveCredentials( client: OAuth2Client ) {
    const content = await fsPromises.readFile( CREDENTIALS_PATH, "utf-8" );
    if( ! content ) {
      throw new NotFoundError( "Credintials Not Found" );
    }
    const keys = JSON.parse( content );
    if( ! keys ) {
      throw new NotFoundError( "Keys Not Found" );
    }
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify( {
      client_id: key.client_id,
      client_secret: key.client_secret,
      refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
      type: "authorized_user",
    } );
    await fsPromises.writeFile( TOKEN_PATH, payload ).catch( ( error ) => {
      throw new ServiceUnavailableError( error );
    } );
  }
    }

